# Java bytecode to machine code

Tags: java

Can we convert Java byte-code to machine code in a Windows that will work without the JVM  ? there are many tools that wrap Jar application into an executable like [Launch4J](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/)  but it's always an application that depend to JVM.

Comment: http://gcc.gnu.org/java/

Comment: @arshajii Slightly better link might be - https://gcc.gnu.org/java/gcj2.html

Comment: Better or not, but certainly more enlightening: https://gcc.gnu.org/java/status.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it has been pointed out, [GCJ](http://gcc.gnu.org/java/) is the way to go:

> GCJ is a portable, optimizing, ahead-of-time compiler for the Java
>   Programming Language. It can compile Java source code to Java bytecode
>   (class files) or directly to native machine code, and Java bytecode to
>   native machine code.

They do [have a manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.0/gcc/) to get you started.

Comment: Note that it does not support a recent version of Java and you will still need runtime libraries, so it is of limited practical use.

Comment: For all practical purposes, GCJ has been a dead man walking ever since Sun open sourced Java under the same license. Today there is **[VMkit](http://vmkit.llvm.org/)** and some other projects, but they typically don't support Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Without a JVM, running Java Programs can be achieved using GraalVM with alleged performance improvements. See https://www.graalvm.org/22.1/reference-manual/native-image/

Answer (score 0):

Another option is using IKVM and .NET6+. IKVM is converting Java to a .NET Application. Under .NET 6+, one can then turn this into a natively compiled application, so .NET does not need to exist on the target Windows system.

Note that performance may suffer, if you go this route.